# MySQL Insert INTO using SELECT from another table with additional data

Tags: mysql

### What I'm Trying To Achieve

I'm trying to insert a record from one table into another, but also add additional data that isn't sourced from the second table.

### Example Problem

I'm trying to put insert field1, field2 and field3 into tableA. field1 and field2 are sourced from tableB. However, field3 is some additional arbitrary data that I will populate using my application.

### The Query So Far

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, field3) SELECT (field1, field2) FROM tableB WHERE id='1'
```

### The Issue

Field3 is not being inserted at the moment as the above query doesn't have the field in the query. I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, field3) (SELECT (field1, field2) FROM tableB WHERE id='1'), 'somevalue';
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I don't want field3 to be set to NULL or an empty string. I need to populate that column, however I need it to be populated with data from outside of the scope of the INSERT. In the example above, it should be 'somevalue'.

Comment: INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, field3) (SELECT (field1, field2, 'somevalue') FROM tableB WHERE id='1');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would just include the constant in the `select` list:

```
INSERT INTO tableA(field1, field2, field3)
    SELECT field1, field2, 'somevalue'
    FROM tableB
    WHERE id = '1';
```

Also, don't surround the columns in a `select` in parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

Number of  Insert statement columns should match with select columns when you insert data from another table  In Your case this thing possible

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, field3) 
SELECT (field1, field2,Null or 'Somevalue') FROM tableB WHERE id='1' // You have to pass some value or null or ''
```

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I don't want field3 to be a NULL or empty value. I need to set it, but outside of the scope of the INSERT.

Comment: can you please tell me what somevalue should be in field3?

Comment: Exactly that, 'somevalue'. It doesn't matter what it is, but it just isn't a value that is held or returned from tableB.

Comment: kk done one thing pass null right now than update null with you somevalue whenever you want..@BigPun

Comment: That would result in multiple queries which is exactly what this sort of sub querying is intended to avoid. See the marked answer.